# Spring Scheduler or Spring Batch for task?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

Have a task to delete files based on some conditions. This task should run everyday at some time. Should we use Spring Boot and scheduler for this task.
Or Spring Batch + Scheduler would be good. Also **can this task be parallely processed using partitioning in Spring Batch**.

Thanks

Comment: Spring Batch and scheduling are 2 different concerns. Only using Spring Batch won't help you because you still need something to schedule the batch job.

Comment: Hi Deinum. Have updated the question.

Comment: Why would you need partitions for parallel processing? Looks like you are overengineering a simply cleanup script.

Comment: Spring scheduling would be enough if you dont have huge number of files. I would suggest you to start with it..if required you can add batch later.

Comment: @SangamBelose- The task is to delete millions of files from multiple folders.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you pls suggest what can be used for parallel process of deleting multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you even need spring batch here.
Spring batch would be useful if you need:

- handling transactions
- robustness/restartability of jobs

For your plain case of deleting files all you could use - some kind of scheduler together with spring integration. For spring integration you will just configure some kind of poller which will trigger deletion of files:

```
@Bean
public PollerMetadata myPoller() {
  return Pollers.cron("cron expression here")
                .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem (without leveraging Spring Batch) you can combine two simple techniques. To execute your task for running once a day in the simplest way I would recommend a [simple Spring scheduled task](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). For doing multiple file operations in parallel, there are parallel streams respective the fork/join framework. Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) to get some ideas.